# Textchanged event in mvc for a Textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginer in mvc.I am working on an application where i need to change the value of a textbox after i enter a value in it and press TAB.For example when i enter **1** in textbox and press tab it should display **+1** ie i need to concatinate a **+** sign to the text i enter.SO to do this i am trying to raise a textchanged event for the textbox.How can i do it.When i googled it i found that it can be done using javascript.But i dont know how to do that,pls give me some suggessions.

Code:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.text)--textbox
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use jQuery and subscribe to the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event which will be triggered when the input field looses focus:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_your_textbox').blur(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var newValue = value + '1';
        $(this).val(newValue);
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use a javascript framework such as jQuery you could achieve the same with plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('id_of_your_textbox').onblur = function() {
        var value = this.value;
        var newValue = value + '1';
        this.value = newValue;
    };
};
```

Note: this will add the string value `1` to the existing text. If you wanted to perform an integer addition you need to parse the current value first. You could use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) methods (depending on the data type) for that:

```
var value = parseInt($(this).val());
if (!isNaN(value)) {
    var newValue = value + 1;
    $(this).val(newValue);
} else {
    alert('You have entered an invalid integer value');
}
```

And here's how to assign a deterministic id to your text field that you could use in your javascript selectors:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.text, new { id = "id_of_your_textbox" })
```