# ASP.NET MVC Razor catch textchange event when user editing input filed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have an input field:

```
<input asp-for="saleOrderDetail.Description" class="form-control" />
```

I want to execute some code when the user is editing that field but I don't know how to do this. Anyone can help me? Thanks you for reading!

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233576/asp-net-onkeyup-event-for-textbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211873/textchanged-event-in-mvc-for-a-textbox